# How to read pixel values in Silverlight Image control?

Tags: silverlight, image

Is it possible to read pixel values from an Image control in Silverlight 4 without copying Image pixels into a WritableBitmap?  I know how to do that with the WritableBitmap.

I would like to read the value of a pixel my mouse is over.

I can track my mouse move over the loaded image in the Image control reading relevant XY coordinates.  I would like to avoid allocating a WritableBitmap object and do the expensive pix copy.

Thanks for suggestions.
V

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

You can render the Image once in the MouseButtonDown event and use the rendered bitmap in the MouseMove event to get better performance.